# Clicking on dynamically loaded child elements in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a static div that is always part of the DOM with the id `#validUsers`, within that div we have children with the class `.valid-user` - these are dynamically added to the page via a button click. Nested within each `.valid-user` is an unordered list with 10 list items. Ideally, clicking on any of the list items in a `.valid-user` should trigger the click function, but that's not happening.

`$('#validUsers').on('click', '.valid-user', function (event) { ... })` triggers when we click anywhere in new or existing `.valid-user` divs, but:

`$('#validUsers').on('click', '.valid-user li', function (event) { ... })` doesn't trigger at all when we click on the list items, or the larger div itself.

Any ideas as to why adding `li` to the selector causes it to select nothing at all?

Html:

```
<div id = "validUsers">
  <div class="valid-user">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="dropdown>
          <ul class="valid-user-type-list">
             <li>Type1</li>
             <li>Type2</li>
             <li>Type3</li>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
$('#validUsers').on('click', '.valid-user li', function () {
  console.log("Clicked on list item");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="validUsers">
  <div class="valid-user">
    <div class="row">
    <label>Valid User Types</label>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <ul class="valid-user-type-list">
          <li>Type1</li>
          <li>Type2</li>
          <li>Type3</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hard to say without some example Html, please add some.

Comment: Given your description, and the *code provided*, this should work.  So it must be something that you've not provided, eg the `li` not being a child of `.valid-user` or some other code on the `li` that stops propagation.   Without a snippet that *demonstrates* the issue, it's just guess work.   Please [edit] your question, click `[<>]` and provided enough code (html/js) to *demonstrate the issue*.

Comment: As your edit shows, it works fine as provided - so there must be some other issue, somewhere else.

Comment: Beat me to the reply, haha. I think the issue might be in the "dropdown" class div, which turns lists into dropdowns (as you might expect). I figure that's what's interfering with it. In any case, it's good to know my selector isn't the problem, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: If you have a wrapper to make it a "dropdown" that that wrapper likely moves the content to `<body>` so that it's not restricted to the `row`.   How do you convert the div/ul to a "dropdown"?  is it a third-party plugin (similar to [tag:select2])?    There should be an API - ie it should raise events that you can listen to.

Comment: Alternatively, change your event handler to `$(document).on('click', '.valid-user li',...`

Comment: When I inspect the options of the dropdown, there's no <body> element. Something I forgot to mention however was that I was able to click these list items when they weren't being dynamically added with `$(".valid-user li").click(function () {...})`. I'm not sure why switching to on() would change that...

Comment: You don't know where `<body>` is in your HTML file?

Comment: Oops, sorry, I misunderstood you. <body> is obviously there. Each of these dynamically added `.valid-user`s are from partial views, but again, not sure why I could target list items already within the dom, but not dynamically added ones, even with .on().